# Does plants ever absorb radio waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I know radio waves transmit very easily through plants but do they absorb certain frequency and do they have reflection coefficient for radio waves,if they do how to calculate them.

Comment: Yes they do. Specifically the oak branch that grew to block my TV disk from receiving the Astra 2 satellite signal!

Comment: yes they do, and they also scatter so there is a special art called FPR (foliage penetrating radar)

Comment: FPR operates in low frequencies so that they pass through most of the objects and are reflected by human bodies,isn't contradicting?.